# How modify Office365 Onenote web view to hide Navigation Panel

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onenote

the question is how can I  modify the WopiFrame.aspx view to Hide Navigation Panel in Office365 Online OneNote for a specific tenant ?? With some AddIn,  With Css, with configuration, or any other option ?

My client  want that the users dont modify the structure of sections, only modify the page of the link! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check the article here: [How to Hide Navigation in OneNote Online](https://itgroove.net/oh365eh/2018/02/05/hide-navigation-onenote-online/), in this way, we only to view just the page you're working on and remove the menus.

If you want to make some users don't modify the structure of sections, only can modify the page of the link, per my knowledge, it can't provide a way to do this requirement. we can set the file for the users to only can read or edit.

As WopiFrame.aspx page store in the server side, we can modify it with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, i saw this article, but i need force to open in this mode, i´m trying with Office Add-in, but i don´t found the solution.

Comment: It is by design.